# Automate tests for a WebAPI REST service

Tags: json, rest, testing, asp.net-web-api, automated-tests

What kind of tests/automated tests you recommend for a REST service (based on ASP.NET WebAPI)?
There are of course unit tests but beside that it would be necessary to assure that after going live with a certain version, any further changes to that specific version exposes a compatible json (we assumed that adding new fields to a json would be ok for a client).

Answer (score 1):

For tests on the REST API, I use [Robot Framework](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) along with the (great) [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

I come up with tests like:

```
*** settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  requests

*** test cases ***
simpleRequest
${result} =  get  http://echo.jsontest.com/framework/robot-framework/api/rest
Should Be Equal  ${result.status_code}  ${200}
${json} =  Set Variable  ${result.json()}
${framework} =  Get From Dictionary  ${json}  framework
Should Be Equal  ${framework}  robot-framework
${api} =  Get From Dictionary  ${json}  api
Should Be Equal  ${framework}  rest
```

I gave some more details in a [blog post](http://laurent.bristiel.com/robot-framework-rest-and-json/).

Answer (score 0):

For REST services, I generally try to set up some tests in [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) (a Javascript testing framework) to go along with the unit tests. I've found that it works well for this sort of thing. Below is an snippet of checking JSON coming back from a REST service (using jQuery to make the call).

```
asyncTest("Test Some JSON Call", function() {
    var url = "http://localhost:5555/myservice";
    rest_test_jsonp(url, function(data, status){
        ok(data != null);
        ok(data.some_array.length > 0);
    });
});

function rest_test_jsonp(url, callback) {
   $.jsonp({
      "url": url+"&callback=?",
      "success": function(data, status, message) {
          callback(data, status, message);
          start();
      },
      "error": function(data, status, message) {
          callback(data, status, message);
          start();
      }
    });
}
```

It also allows you to run these tests in a HTML page, which is nice for demonstrating functionality to stakeholders.